# How to retrieve a value from list android

Tags: android, list

I have a list specialties having 75 items that has two values id and name.

```
 private List specialties;
```

I would like to get the name without using a loop something like below

```
 specialties.get(0).name;
```

I get an error saying `can't resolve name`. Is there any way to retrieve name from the values list.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using model for the same?

Comment: yes i have a model specialties

Comment: there should be a `getter()` for name i.e `specialties.get(0).getName();`

Comment: and You are using adapter also ?

Comment: Check the modifier of name. Should be private in your case

Comment: encapsulation your code

Comment: Make your list instance with `User` model class like  `List<User> userArrayList= new ArrayList<>();` after then you can used `specialties.get(0).getName();`

Comment: specialties.get(0).name its in  javascript, in android u have to create getter and setter to retrieve it from the model. to get name, u must create getname() method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a class (Model) to get and set the ID and Name property:-

```
 public class ClassName {

        private String id;
        private String name;

        public ClassName(String mId, String mName){
            this.id=mId;
            this.name=mName;
        }
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
        public void setName(String sName) {
            this.name = sName;
        }
        public String getId() {
            return id;
        }
        public void setId(String sId) {
            this.id = sId;
        }
    }
```

In your Activity:-

Define a List having the **ClassName** type of objects.

```
List<ClassName> mList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Now access the property **name** like this:-

```
mList.get(0).getName();
mList.get(0).getId();
```

Answer (score 5):

try the following:

```
public class Clone {

    private int Id;
    private String name;

    public int getId() {
        return Id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        Id = id;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
  }
```

and use

```
private List<Clone> arrayList = new ArrayList();

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            Clone helloItem = new Clone();
            helloItem.setId(i);
            helloItem.setName("I'm Clone no - " + i);
            arrayList.add(helloItem);
        }

        Log.d("check", "get item - " + arrayList.get(0).getName());
```

hope it help.

Answer (score 3):

I want to suggest you. You should declare name with public access. If it is not public, use public getter and setter method.Call getName() method.

```
public class YourClass{

 private int id;
 private String name;

  public YourClass(int id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

 public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

 }

 private List<YourClass> specialties = new ArrayList<YourClass>;
 ...//add data into list...
 specialties.add(new YourClass( 1 , "John")); 

  ...// retrieve data 
 specialties.get(position).getName();
```

Answer (score 2):

You have declared your list as **`private List specialties;`** you can not access it like this **`specialties.get(0).name;`**

You  need declare your list like this **`private List<YourModelClass> specialties;`**

**SAMPLE DEMO**

If you want add model class in your list than than check this example
create model class like this

```
public class User {
    String name, email;

    public User(String name, String email) {
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

Now use like this in your list

```
List<User> userArrayList= new ArrayList<>();
```

To add data inside list like this

```
userArrayList.add(new User("Nilesh","abc@gmail.com"));
```

To get data from your list use like this

```
userArrayList.get(0).getEmail();
userArrayList.get(0).getEmail();
```

or

```
for (int i=0;i<userArrayList.size();i++){
    userArrayList.get(i).getName();
    userArrayList.get(i).getEmail();

}
```

Comment: I think all the newbies just jealous of better and more complete answer. ☺

Comment: WRONG -> specialties.get(0).name;

RIGHT ->  specialties.get(0); I didn't get this I mean if the name is a public field in your model class then it's still possible to get the name right ? ,forget the coding standards. specialties.get(0).getName() would have made more sense. Ps. I am not the down voter